# Error while getting postgresql identity value to the variable in SSIS Execute SQL Task

Tags: postgresql, ssis

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "varjobactivityid": "Value does not fall within the expected range.".

I am getting above error while retrieving last inserted id from postgresql to SSIS variable. In MSSQL we have SCOPT_IDENTITY().

I have tried with `RETURNING id`, `currval('persons_id_seq')` and `currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('persons','id'))` but not working. I guess issue is with ODBC driver.

Below is the code which I am using to get last inserted id from variable

```
"INSERT INTO table1 (targettable,filename,processeddatetimeutc) 
    VALUES ('tablename', '" + @[User::filename]+ "', '" + (DT_STR, 30, 1252) GETUTCDATE()+ "');
RETURNING activityid as id"
```

**ResultSet:** Singlerow;

**SSIS variable datatype:** int32;

**Postgresql datatype:** serial (int4)

I also tried using **ExecValueVariable** as the variable in which I have capture the result but every time output is 1

Comment: How do you have the resultset configured?  For the column name, try `1` instead of `0` or `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these settings
Try changing the `resultname to 1` for ODBC connections.

[image]

[image]